# Add borders and/or leave spaces for R Shiny Dashboardheader, Tabpanel, etc

Tags: html, r, shiny, shinydashboard

Due to the design of my app, I would like to give some spaces between each shiny items. In particular, I would like to learn the following:

1. How to add a color border between the shiny dashboardheader and the sidepanel & body?
2. How to add space so that the body part is not immediate adjacent to the sidebar and header?
3. How to give more clear separation between the title tabs of tabpanels?

I marked these three in an example figure below. Hope it can help clarify things. Any advice is appreciated! Thank you!

[image]

Comment: You can use [css](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html) [margin](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp) properties for this. For specific help add some code, please.

Comment: Thank you@ismirsehregal I am not very familiar with css but will take a look. I don't have codes to share yet. For margin - can this also add a underline border as well?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `?hr()`. Please see [this](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/tag-glossary.html).